# hijackthis log from a slow windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

My windows7 machine probably got infected by some kind of virus and/or malware. The system boot up is tediously time consuming and even after a the successful boot, everything is way too slow. A double click to an directory takes about 3 min to process, and during all this time the harddisk LED on my CPU keeps glowing rather than the usual keep-blinking process.

My usual solution is to run an antivirus scan, but unfortunately I haven't installed an antivirus on this machine. Another option I would go for is the System Restore, but this time around I haven't been able to do that. My final hope was to recover using a bootable DVD but I haven't been able to revert all the harmful changes to my system.

But somehow I happened to get hijackThis running and here's the [log](http://pastebin.com/55BPAgR7) from system scan.

Its already too late to install an antivirus or registry cleaner software(s), I guess. So what can I do to save my PC?

Comment: By chance, you wouldn’t happen to have a large HOSTS file or use SpyBot would you?

Comment: Your HijackThis log is clean; you might want to consider to get rid of Vuze and Conduit toolbars because of possible tracking behavior, but none of these would affect your performance in general. If in doubt, you can [run OTL](http://majorgeeks.com/OTL_OldTimers_List-It_d7074.html) and do a Quick Scan without changing any settings. You can share this log on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com). However, I feel like this is a driver or hardware problem... :(

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something is making excessive use of the hard-drive and perhaps also the CPU, thus bogging the system down.

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what process(es) are accessing the file-system (select only the File filter) and [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to find out what process(es) are using the CPU (make sure to enable the CPU graph to make it easier to spot the culprit: `right-click the column header->Select Columns->Processes->History`).

Answer (score 1):

If you think hijackthis will help, you can paste your log into the form at [hijackthis.de](http://hijackthis.de) and it will analyze it for you, flagging anything that may be of concern or indicative of something dangerous (like a trojan). However, be aware that hijackthis directly modifies the registry and using it (and this site, which is only community-supported and not comprehensive) can damage your computer beyond what state it's in right now. Proceed with caution.

Comment: HijackThis.de is bad, it gathers information from about any user rather than people that know what they are doing. It's always better to go through the log yourself, *line by line* using a guide...

Comment: @TomWijsman I've used it a few times with success. Of course in the end you have to make sure you really want to do what you're clicking on. But it's a good method to at least parse through the log and make sense of it without spending too much effort. However, if you're using HijackThis!, you should already know this, because it is an advanced utility, and not for those who don't know what they're doing.

Comment: I prefer Automatic Runs. I've actually made a log splitter once for HijackThis which you provide a log and then it uses known rules or patterns to split the file such that you only get the unknown / bad lines out of it. These days HijackThis has made place for [OTL (OldTimer's List)](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/files/file/398-otl-oldtimers-list-it/) which goes a lot further. But yet, I prefer Microsoft tools...